# iOS UITextView: How to create a double-spaced input text field?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, textkit

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410170/ios-uitextview-increase-line-spacing-without-changing-the-height-of-the-cursor). I'm trying to create a double-spaced UITextView for entering text.

In my custom UITextView, I've overwritten and -caretRectForPosition: to limit the height of the cursor. But now when I select text, the height of the selection rectangle was still too high:
[image: red selection rectangle is too tall]

I tried to overcome this by overriding UIView's -selectionRectsForRange. Unfortunately, the objects in that return array are UITextSelectionRects, which is an immutable subclass. So I made my own subclass, made the height mutable, and changed it in a loop like so:

```
- (NSArray *)selectionRectsForRange:(UITextRange *)range
{
    NSArray *originalSectionRects = [super selectionRectsForRange:range];
    NSMutableArray *newSelectionRects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:originalSectionRects.count];

    // For all the UITextSelectionRects
    for (UITextSelectionRect *selectionRect in originalSectionRects) {
        // Use one with a custom height
        DCTextSelectionRect *newSelectionRect = [[DCTextSelectionRect alloc] initWithTextSelectionRect:selectionRect rectHeight:self.font.lineHeight];
        [newSelectionRects addObject:newSelectionRect];
    }
    return newSelectionRects.copy;
}
```

Now the selection rectangles are the right size, but the blue handles used to grow & shrink the selection area are trapped in the top left corner.

[image: handles are trapped in the top left. selection height is correct]

Any idea what's causing the handles to be in the wrong place? What can I try to get them in the right place?

Comment: I've found a [completely different solution](https://github.com/downie/DoubleSpacedTextView) to this problem, but it uses brute force to recalculate the line fragment rectangles on every text change. If I could figure out what's causing the handles to flee to the top left corner, it would still be a much more efficient (and preferred) solution.

Comment: can you attach implementation of DCTextSelectionRect?